# grep locks up after searching thru spool/postfix

Tags: ubuntu, grep, postfix

I'm trying to search for a text string **inside a file** on my server, with the command:

```
grep -iRl "database_password" /
```

BUT! it seems to hang itself after going thru postfix directories.

This is the last I see on the screen:

```
grep: /var/spool/postfix/private/relay: No such device or addressgrep: /var/spool/postfix/private/policyd-spf: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/private/discard: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/private/virtual: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/public/flush: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/public/postlog: No such device or address
grep: /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup: No such device or addressgrep: /var/spool/postfix/public/showq: No such device or address
```

Then nothing.. I can use Ctrl-C to stop it.

So I'm wondering two things, why does it "seem" to stop? (waited over 2 hours), and why are grep reporting "**no such device or address**" on just these directories? it doesn't say anything about other directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... why [is] grep reporting "no such device or address" on ... these directories?

Those aren't directory, they're Unix domain sockets:

```
# file /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup: socket
```

The message you're seeing there isn't unexpected when trying to read from such a file, and isn't likely related to what you're perceiving as `grep` "hanging".

> ... it seems to hang itself after going thru [the] postfix directories.

One thing to consider is, there are files under `/` that will return an infinite stream of bytes (e.g., `/dev/urandom`).  It's possible that `grep` is reading one of those files looking for your pattern.

Consider for example:

```
# grep $(uuidgen) /dev/urandom
```

That'll likely run a *really* long time.

I suggest that you be a little more selective with your target search directory.

Comment: aha.. is there someway to tell grep to ignore those directories?

Comment: @AdamLarsson what are you trying to do here? There's no point in searching through `/dev` or `/sys` or `/proc` for instance.

Comment: Also look out for named pipes (FIFOs). `grep` will just sit there forever waiting for something to write to them. In general, if you want actual files, `-type f` is very helpful. Or `'(' -type d -o -type f ')'` if you must.

Comment: @terdon I was trying to find a text string somewhere on my computer .

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm looking inside the files, not for a file..

Comment: @AdamLarsson yes, precisely. If one of these "files" is actually a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), the `grep` would hang there for ever waiting for something to write to the file. Basically, searching through `/` indiscriminately isn't a good solution for, well, for anything really. You might want to ask a new question about how to do what you really need here since your approach (which is the obvious, natural and logical approach) won't work.

Comment: @AdamLarsson  FIFOs (arguably) don't have an "inside", and /dev is a container for raw devices and partitions. `grep` has no options to distinguish the types of things in the tree below `/`. The trick is to use `find` to search for such files as you need, and then its `-exec` option to run a command on each of those files in turn.